# Let B be an m×n matrix and let AB be a k×n matrix. If rank B= rank (AB), show that null (A) ∩ im(B)={0}.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have so far shown that null(B) = null(AB) by proving that null(B) is a subset of null(AB) and that the dimensions of both null(B) and null(AB) are equivalent. However, I am unsure of how to continue.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an element $ x\in null(A) \cap Im(B)$ In other words,$A(x) = 0$ and $x = B(y)$ for some $y$.
$A(B(y))= AB(y)= 0$. Since you have shown that the null spaces are the same, this implies that $y \in null(B)$. Conclude that $x = B(y)= 0$. Can you finish from here?